# ioutil.ReadFile - no such file or directory

Tags: go

For the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("shakespeare.txt")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print(err)
    }

    str := string(b)

    text := strings.Split(str, " ")
    fmt.Print(len(text))
}
```

---

Below is the error:

```
code$
code$
code$ ls src/github.com/myhub/cs61a/
caching  counters  expressions  gomap  lab_00  Main.go  Readme.md  shakespeare.txt
code$ 
code$ go run src/github.com/myhub/cs61a/Main.go 
open shakespeare.txt: no such file or directory1code$ 
code$ 
code$
```

---

How to refer a text file located in same directory location of `Main.go`?

Comment: Note that your should literally _never_ run your application with `go run <file*>`. Never. Either use `go run <package-import-path>` or `go run <folder>` if you insist on not using the normal `go build` followed by `./<generated-executable>` way.

Answer (score 11):

One problem with running a Go program with the `go run` command is that the directory of the built executable binary is **not** in the same directory where your "Main.go" file is located.

For instance, here's a program which prints the directory of the binary:

```golang
func main() {
        dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(dir)
}
```

This outputs on my laptop:

```
go run Main.go
/var/folders/2v/7n_r3hf539x6f6kf0m2zn5z40000gp/T/go-build855783190/b001/exe
```

You can build the binary first and have it placed in the same directory as your file.

```sh
go build -o myapp Main.go
```

Now we can print the actual directory where the binary lives:

```sh
./myapp
/Users/james/Desktop
```

If you need to hardcode the name of the file in your program and assume it lives in the same directory as your binary, you can now do this:

```golang
func main() {
    dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    path := filepath.Join(dir, "shakespeare.txt")
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    str := string(b)
    text := strings.Split(str, " ")
    fmt.Println(len(text))
}
```

Again, build then run the binary (I just added two words in my test file named "shakespeare.txt").

```sh
go build -o myapp Main.go
./myapp
2
```

Another option is to have your program accept the path of the file to read as an argument. This way it doesn't matter where your binary or your file lives since you pass that in directly.

```golang
func main() {
        b, err := ioutil.ReadFile(os.Args[1])
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        str := string(b)
        text := strings.Split(str, " ")
        fmt.Println(len(text))
}
```

You can run this with `go run` or build it first as before:

```sh
go run Main.go ~/Desktop/shakespeare.txt
2
```