# Golang grpc: no transport security set

Tags: go, ssl, grpc-go

I'm currently researching and trying to implement hashing/salting of password in my `Golang` server. Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17958384/10464730), I learned about the stuff I needed. I already got the hashing and salting part, then I researched about TLS. I almost used the regular `Golang` way of doing things but I was also using `gRPC` so I looked for how to add TLS for that, and it was quite simple. I added the codes mentioned on the [official documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/), but somehow that doesn't work.

To generate the `.cert` and `.key`, I followed this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/denji/12b3a568f092ab951456). Then this is what my code looks like.

//Server

```
certFile, certFileErr := os.ReadFile("server.crt")

if certFileErr != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to read cert file: %v", certFileErr)
}

keyFile, keyFileErr := os.ReadFile("server.key")

if keyFileErr != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to read key file: %v", keyFileErr)
}

creds, _ := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile(string(certFile), string(keyFile))
mServ := grpc.NewServer(grpc.Creds(creds))

lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:50051")
```

//Client

```
certFile, certFileErr := os.ReadFile("server.crt")

if certFileErr != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to read cert file: %v", certFileErr)
}

creds, _ := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile(string(certFile), "")
conn, err := grpc.Dial("localhost:50051", grpc.WithTransportCredentials(creds))

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to pass a reference of the files to `gRPC`, so I thought I'd just do a regular file read. With all those stuff, when I a run the server side, it works fine. But when I run the client side, I get this error.

> grpc: no transport security set (use
> grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()) explicitly or
> set credentials)

The error is quite confusing. I already want to not use security, but it's complaining that I'm downgrading. It's my first time doing this stuff, so I have no idea what's the regular process to implement security on a login.

Update:

After logging the error, it seems like my code can't find the `.cert` file. Which is weird because the path I used was already auto suggested by my IDE itself.

Comment: `creds, _ := credentials.NewClientTLSFromFile`, please do not ignore errors. Check and log the error. And this func accepts a parameter as the path to the CA cert. See the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc/credentials#NewClientTLSFromFile). You should pass the path to the CA which is used to sign `server.crt` here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this seems like quite a simple issue. I was using `go run` when running my code, which seems to make the `.exe` file be placed in a different directory as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61536281/10464730), so my code won't be able to find the certification files. Doing a `go build` fixed my issue.